# ImportError: No module named scipy.stats._continuous_distns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have Spark job which at the end uses saveAsTable to write the dataframe into an internal table w/ a given name.

The dataframe is created using different steps which one of them is using "beta" method in scipy, where I imported it through => from scipy.stats import beta. It's running on google cloud w/ 20 worker nodes but I get the following error which is complaining about scipy package,

```
  Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: 
  Job aborted due to stage failure: 
  Task 14 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: 
  Lost task 14.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 518, name-w-3.c.somenames.internal, 
  executor 23): org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonException: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 364, in main
  func, profiler, deserializer, serializer = read_command(pickleSer, infile)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/worker.py", line 69, in read_command
  command = serializer._read_with_length(file)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 172, in 
  _read_with_length
  return self.loads(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/serializers.py", line 583, in loads
  return pickle.loads(obj)
  ImportError: No module named scipy.stats._continuous_distns
```

Any idea or solutions?

I tried to pass the library as well for the spark job:

```
"spark.driver.extraLibraryPath" : "/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip",
"spark.driver.extraClassPath" :"/usr/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the library installed on all the nodes in the cluster?
You can simply do a

```
pip install --user scipy
```

I do it in AWS EMR using the bootstrap action, There should be a similar way on Google cloud as well

Comment: It works, I was looking for a solution to pass the library to the worker nodes from master node instead of installing it.

Comment: Try using "spark.files"

Comment: already tried that too. the same error. I think that should've worked... but I guess the python version was not the same as the file passed through spark.files. So at the end i had to go to each worker node downgrade the python version and install scipy for that ... not a smart solution